# How to add a html page in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I'm using Doxywizard to generate the Doxygen document websites and I have another HTML page such as "some_page.html". Is it possible to add a link under the "Related Pages" to display this HTML? I read doxygen document. The "\page" command does not help on showing HTML page.

Comment: It is possible to add your own / user pages, see documentation in paragraph "Changing the layout of pages". I'm not sure t\whether or not you can directly add the to "Related Pages".

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am currently using Doxygen 1.8.20.